# jQuery: add content to end of div

Tags: jquery

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="region-list" id="region_North_America">
    <strong>North America</strong>
</div>
```

and want to add more divs after the strong element to result:

```
<div class="region-list" id="region_North_America">
    <strong>North America</strong>
    <div> ... </div>
    <div> ... </div>
    <div> ... </div>
</div>
```

I am trying this:

```
var row_str = '<div>content here</div>';
$('#region_North_America div:last').html(row_str);
```

However, there is no change to the html. This is probably so since there is no `div` within the element selected.

I know that the js is making it to this code because I can print the content of row_str to the console.

So, how can I get to the end of that container element to add the new items?

Thx.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Try:

```
$("#region_North_America").append(row_str);
```

using [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append).

Answer (score 8):

Or:

```
$("<div>content here</div>").appendTo("#region_North_America");
```

To create the element on the fly, and place it in the document.
Using the [appendTo](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo) method.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will just place html in the last div within #region_North_America.  Use the append function.

```
$("div.region-list").append(row_str);
```